# Does the Gram Schmidt process give a unique orthonormal family?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Intuitively, I think it doesn't as depending on the basis you start from you will get different sets of orthonormal familys. Is this right? Is there any way it could give a unique family, that every other starting basis would result in the same orthonormal family? And depending on those answers could I have hints to a formal proof? Thanks

Further thought: if I have my vector space as $Mat(1;\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ then surely the only basis I can start from is $[1]$ in which case the orthonormal family must be unique?

Sorry this is not letting me comment, if you start with an orthogonal basis, you will just get that basis back. Does this imply that if the basis you start with is orthogonal then no other basis will be able to produce it after the gram schmidt process?

Comment: @azarel: Please put that as an answer. (If you feel awkward about answering a question with no explanation, just write write "Hint:" before it. That always alleviates my guilt)

Comment: @EricStucky Ok, I'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: Note: if your vector space is one-dimensional, then there is a unique orthonormal basis (up to sign).  If your vector space is zero-dimensional, then there is a unique (empty) orthonormal basis.

Comment: Are you asking if the process returns a unique output given a specific input?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What happen if you already start with two different orthogonal basis?